# count returns <<air>> when there's nothing to group by

Tags: oracle, group-by, count, coalesce

Here's my SQL:

```
select 
  count(*)
from
  sysdba.dw_cmap_arf_tmp
left join SYSDBA.TABLE1 rrc 
  on rrc.part_work_order = pwo
left join sysdba.TABLE2 R
  on rrc.run_number = R.RUN_NUMBER
where 
  upper(run_type) like '%FEE%'
group by 
  pwo;
```

When there's nothing to group by, **count** returns --air--.  It's null nor is it blank.  I have modified the above SQL as the following to prove.

```
select 
  '>>' || count(*) || '<<' as blah
from
  sysdba.dw_cmap_arf_tmp
left join SYSDBA.TABLE1 rrc 
  on rrc.part_work_order = pwo
left join sysdba.TABLE2 R
  on rrc.run_number = R.RUN_NUMBER
where 
  upper(run_type) like '%ANNEAL%'
group by 
  pwo;
```

When I, however, write a statement above to perform an update, I got null.  So tried coalesce, but got the same thing.

Does anyone know what I can do to replace --air-- with null or 0?  Thanks!

P.S. I have did something research, but couldn't find anything...apologize in advance, if there's already a similar question out there.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "When there's nothing to group by" do you mean the `pwo` can contain nulls and the criteria is returning data where all rows returned have a null `pwo` value?  And do you really have a user named `sysdba` on an Oracle database? That could confuse some people...

Comment: You have different criteria in your two examples.  Can you post the output of both examples using the same criteria for `RUN_TYPE`?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you currently have (based on Scott's EMP table): as there's no department 50, you get *no rows selected* (which is the *air* you're talking about, I presume).

```
SQL> with your_current_query as
  2    (select count(*) cnt
  3     from emp
  4     where deptno = &deptno
  5     group by job
  6    )
  7  select cnt
  8  from your_current_query;
Enter value for deptno: 50

no rows selected
```

Just to show that it actually returns something if there are some data there:

```
SQL> /
Enter value for deptno: 30

       CNT
----------
         4
         1
         1

SQL>
```

---

OK; now, to do *something* with the situation where there are no rows selected, use union with a "dummy" row selected from the `DUAL` table:

```
SQL> with your_current_query as
  2    (select count(*) cnt
  3     from emp
  4     where deptno = &deptno
  5     group by job
  6    )
  7  select cnt
  8  from your_current_query
  9  -- add this: if YOUR_CURRENT_QUERY doesn't return anything, union it with
 10  -- a select from dual
 11  union all
 12  select 0
 13  from dual
 14  where 0 = (select count(*) from your_current_query);
Enter value for deptno: 50

       CNT
----------
         0

SQL>
```

So: even though there are no employees in department 50, you got 0 as the result.

Again, to show what happens when there are some rows:

```
SQL> /
Enter value for deptno: 30

       CNT
----------
         4
         1
         1

SQL>
```

---

Finally, your query - rewritten - would look like this:

```
with your_current_query as
  (select 
    count(*) cnt
   from
     sysdba.dw_cmap_arf_tmp
   left join SYSDBA.TABLE1 rrc 
     on rrc.part_work_order = pwo
   left join sysdba.TABLE2 R
     on rrc.run_number = R.RUN_NUMBER
   where 
     upper(run_type) like '%FEE%'
   group by 
     pwo
  )
select cnt from your_current_query
union all
select 0 
from dual
where 0 = (select count(*) from your_Current_query);
```

See if it helps.